# looping in jquery (with .each() method)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made the following code in order to create something like a piano. When you click on a button (`#start_img`) each `.piano` div should get the `press` class and after a short break it should be removed from it again.

Then the function should loop to the next `.piano` div and repeat the same actions there. Doesn't sound too difficult, only problem is that it isn't working. Can anyone explain to me what's wrong with the code?

```js
$('#start_img').on('click', function() {
  $('.piano').each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass('press').delay(900).removeClass('press');
  });
});
```

```css
.press {
  background-color: silver;
}
.piano {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='start_img'>Start</button>

<div id='page'>
  <div class='piano'></div>
  <div class='piano'></div>
  <div class='piano'></div>
  <div class='piano'></div>
  <div class='piano'></div>
  <div class='piano'></div>
  <div class='piano'></div>
  <div class='piano'></div>
  <div class='piano'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your remaining code?

Comment: `.delay(900*index)` try this. I guess you should use a setTimeout instead with a delay just like this `}, 900*index);`

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons.

1. delay() will only work for methods that use the animation queue internally
2. The loop will run instantaneously and therefore add same delay to each instance making them all activate simultaneously

You could do something like

```
piano.each(function(index){
   var $el = $(this);
   setTimeout(function(){
       $el.addClass('press');
       setTimeout(function(){
         $el.removeClass('press');
       }, 880);
   }, (index+1) * 900);// multiply delay by index to increment each one
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Only one question. What do you mean with the animation queue (internally)?

Comment: effects methods basically, ones that have durations

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout with a delay at the particular index.

```
start.on('click', function() {
  var piano = $('.piano');
  piano.each(function(index) {
    var _this = $(this);
    _this.addClass('press');
    setTimeout(function() {
      _this.removeClass('press');
    }, 900 * index);
  });
});
```